# Extracting image of words from a scanned paper

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, scanning

I want get a small image of every word in a lot of scanned books (that is in Persian (Arabic-script)).
I have no experiment in image prossessing.
How can I do that in most efficient way?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you write a script in MATLAB something like this.
a : half of the maximum distance between the letters.(in pixels)
b : half of the minimum distance between the words.(in pixels)
(lets hope a < b )

Threshold the scanned image of the page.

```
I(I < Th) = 0;I(I > Th) = 1;
```

Choose 'Th' by experimenting. You should get a binary image 'I' having 1's where letters are.
Dilate the image.

```
imdilate(I,a);
```

This will connect the letters together.
Remove noise.

```
I = bwareaopen(I,n);
```

this will remove all connected components with less that n pixels.
Do connected component analysis.

```
CC = bwconncomp(I);  
Rect = regionprops(I,'BoundingBox');
```

This will return a list of co-ordinates of a rectangle containing a single word.
Extract the sub-matrix from original copy and write the image using imwrite().